# What is a less common phrase that's similar to 'To the untrained eye...'?

Tags: phrase-requests

I feel that 'to the untrained eye' is somewhat overused/clichéd andam seeking a variation or equivalent.

For instance, would could replace it in the following sentence?

> [*To the untrained eye,*] these men looked every bit a part of the scenery, but it was in the details that one unearthed the truth, and...

I think an equivalent, but lesser-known construction could work better, or even a small adjustment, such as changing 'untrained eye' to 'inexperienced eye' would make it more original. Basically, I'm looking for an alternative and would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: 'If this would be better homed on writing.stackexchange, please let me know and I'll move it' is a tough call, Heartspring. A request for a synonymous fixed phrase is fine on ELU (subject to reasonable research not being omitted), but one for an acceptable novel rephrase is off-topic as not referencing standard usage.

Comment: @JohnLawler The phrase is not intended as an address to the reader, but instead it refers to a discrimination among observers in general. There is an ambiguity between "you" as "somebody in general" and "you, the reader".

Comment: Yes, and excluding any reader from your address is not a normal part of writing.

Comment: Is the word 'eye' mandatory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with "to the untrained eye";  nevertheless, one might wish to use synonyms or slight variants of an expression.

As a variant with little difference, "*to the uninitiated eye*"  is usable almost interchangeably, I would think, although it applies more properly to contexts involving a less practical experience. ([plenty of examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22to%20the%20uninitiated%20eye%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en))

- *to the uninitiated eye*

You may wish to have an expression that is more evocative of the analytical qualities of the mind; the same expressions as above with "eye" replaced with "mind" will correspond to this context.

- *to the untrained mind*, *to the uninitiated mind*

You may also want to insist on the natural gift rather than on training; you might then think proper an expression such as "*to the unperceptive onlooker*".

- *to the unperceptive onlooker/person/observer/masses/public/…*

> ([The Household Economy: Reconsidering The Domestic Mode Of Production - 2019](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_Household_Economy/GgaiDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22the+unperceptive%22&pg=PT64&printsec=frontcover)) While the unperceptive onlooker may see a teenage girl going off herding in the morning as someone “tending her family's animals,” the girl herself perceives the flock as made up of individually-owned animals, jointly tended.

Comment: We wouldn't say *to the uninitiated eye, these men...*; we would say *to the uninitiated, these men...*. We would use *uninitiated* as a nominalized adjective.

Comment: @TinfoilHat What do you make, then, of the multitude of examples (see answer), among which, to boot, there are a great many of recent origin (21st century)? "To the uninitiated" is a possibility, which I should perhaps have included in my answer; nevertheless, what's been found wanting all of a sudden with "to the uninitiated eye", in particular when it explicits the fact that the matter is a question of visual perception?

Comment: The "multitude" is relative. For [*to the uninitiated*](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=110938173), the Corpus of Contemporary American English returns 163 results of which only 4 use *uninitiated* as an adjective in front of a noun. One of those nouns is *eye*. You can search other corpora and Google Ngram and even your Google Books and find similar results. It's relatively rare to find *uninitiated* used as an adjective.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Something has to be wrong with your corpus; In the Google page of a hundred hits referred to in my answer, without scanning the page further than to its middle, I find 45 cases all for the noun "eye", and in all of them the meaning is such as needed to support the answer; furthermore, 20 of them are found after 2000, which shows a regain of interest for this expression in the 21st century (not so much used in the 20th but much used in the 19th). ([ref.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+the+uninitiated+eye&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3))

Comment: How can there be something "wrong" with a [corpus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corpus_linguistics)? If you search Google Books for *to the uninitiated eye*, of course you will find examples. But if you search *to the uninitiated*, at a glance, how many results do you see where *uninitiated* is used as an adjective?

Comment: You say "One of those nouns is eye." It is obviously wrong: more than 45 can't be 1 and those 45 books are not an invention of Google. It seems to me that you did not acquaint yourself with this page of examples,  that you somehow reject this reference altogether. Also, we are not interested in justifying the existence of the nominalized adjective but that of the expression, and the Google research does that.

Comment: If you examine what follows *to the uninitiated* — in any corpus of your choosing, including Google Books — you'll find that it is rare to see *uninitiated* used as an adjective in front of *eye* or any other noun.

Comment: “Inexperienced observer” might work if “eye” is not essential.

Answer (score 0):

[To the untrained eye,] **At a cursory glance/ To your average man in the street/ To the uninitiated/ To the unobservant** these men looked every bit a part of the scenery, but it was in the details that one unearthed the truth,

All the words are available in any reasonable dictionary.

Answer (score -3):

**Guileless** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/guileless))  Free from guile; honest but naive.

```
To the guileless, these men looked....
```

**Undiscerning** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/undiscerning)): not discerning[[Wiktionary:](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/discerning) Of keen insight or good judgement; perceptive].

```
To the undiscerning eye, these men looked....
```

Similarly 'unknowing eye', 'unseeing eye' can also be used.

Comment: +1 for "undiscerning" but -1 for "guileless".

Comment: :) will do. I asked in comments to OP, whether 'eye' is mandatory.